# memset for a given range in an array

Tags: memset

I know how we use memset to set the contents of an array to a particular value. Now, I am interested in something that does the same for a given range.

```
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
//set the content from A[a] to A[b] as '0' without looping
```

I don't want to go through for loop. Please tell if there is some other and efficient method to achieve this.

Comment: I'm pretty certain most versions of `memset()` contain at least one `for` loop. But did you try anything? Maybe something like `memset(A + a, b - a, 0)` but with suitable checking to make sure that `a` and `b` are actually valid indices into the array first?

Comment: Hi! So you mean that whether I use memset or a for loop, it would be the same thing? And what you've told, gives garbage output. :/

Comment: Except on platforms like x86 that have native looping instructions (which may not be used anyway in certain situations due to limitations in iteration count or other instruction set constraints), it's quite likely that a properly constructed `for` loop will generate nearly identical instructions compared with an inlined `memset()` call. But `memset()` tends to be clearer to those who have to review the code down the road, and the compiler/library writers should be providing as near optimal code as possible for it, so it's better to use `memset()` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Oops, I got the arguments out of order on the original comment, as well as making the assumption that we're talking about byte arrays - should be `memset(A + a, 0, (b - a) * sizeof(A[0]))`.

Answer (score 1):

**Assigning values with memset works only with 2 values : 0 and -1**,
Rest will only give garbage values

Still, Let me help you to use memset for a range.
I'm using an example to explain your query below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[10]; // Array of 10 elements with val of 0;
    memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
    // Sets all array elements to 0 

    memset(a+2,-1,sizeof(int)*5);
    // Sets value of array elements from 2 to 6 index equals to -1

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       cout<<a[i]<<" ";
       cout<<endl;

       return 0;
}
```

**Output:** 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0

* I've checked the code on various IDE's before posting.

**Hope it helps a bit!**